# Jquery input radio field add percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, calculator

I need to be able to add a percentage to the total price when a radio button is selected. The code currently works, but only adds a value to the radio button. I need that, but also need to take the total calculated price with addOns and + a percentage to it.

Does anyone know how I can change this with Jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bitlabs/mGLfk/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="price">Estimate Price $<label for="amount1" class="total">0</label></div>

<p class="itemdesc1">How many "Linear Feet" of boards do you have?</p>
<input id="amount1" class="amount" data-for="amount1" />

<div class="addon"><input id="amount2" type="checkbox" value="10.00" class="radio addOn" data-for="amount1" />Add Red $10.00</div>

<div class="addon"><input id="amount3" type="checkbox" value="20.00" class="radio addOn" data-for="amount1" />Add Blue + 20%</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.amount').keypress(function () {
        changeAmount($(this));
    });

    $('.addOn').change(function () {
        var $original = $('#' + $(this).data('for'));
        changeAmount($original);
    });
});

function changeAmount($element) {
    var amount = 0;
    amount = parseFloat($element.val()) * 20;

    if (isNaN(amount)) {
        amount = 0;
    }

    var id = $element.attr('id');

    $('.radio:checked[data-for="' + id + '"]').each(function () {
        amount += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });

    $('label[for=' + id + ']').text(amount.toFixed(0))
}
```

Comment: What error you get in this ??

Comment: do you just want the output to have a "%" sign next to it?

Comment: no error, but if you look at the 2nd checkbox, you see I want to add 20% of the total price, example: Estiamte Price is $200, oncheck adds $20 which is 20% of it - new Estimate is $220

Comment: This should really be two separate functions.  One to add a base amount and one to add a percentage.

Comment: see this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4bitlabs/mGLfk/7/

Comment: In the second checkbox, it has 20% in the value.

Comment: I would suggest to add different class for sum and percentage. First, query all elements with sum and calculate total, then query all percentage elements, calculate sum of percentage and multiply it by base sum.

Comment: Say your Total is $100, if I check the Add Blue + 20%, the new Total is $120 due to it adding in $20 which is 20% of $100.

Comment: 20% of 200$ is 40$, so 240$. Not sure that it is what you want, but have a look : http://jsfiddle.net/mGLfk/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I would rewrite what I understand from your question, please, correct me if I'm wrong...

You have CHECKBOXES, and you have an input where you may write a number of items you want to purchase. Then, you want to know the final price of the items you purchase, applying some considerations depending on what CHECKBOX are clicked.

Well, that said, I'll start first assuring you always trigger an "adding function" when anything changes (let's say, you change the number of inputs, or you click a checkbox). You almost did it, but you pass a parameter and I think that is not necessary. When you'll trigger anytime the calculation, you'll always have the right result.

Other thing, you need to distinguish between "adding checkbox" (adds a price per item) and "percentage checkbox" (adds a percentage to the price), to know what value you have to add. Just add clases to your checkboxes to distinguish between them. I'll add a fiddle:

### Changes:

The clasess in the checkboxes, to know what we want to do with any of them, put attention on the **add** and **percentage** clasess:

```
<div class="addon"><input id="amount2" type="checkbox" value="10.00" class="radio addOn add" data-for="amount1" />Add Red $10.00</div>

<div class="addon"><input id="amount3" type="checkbox" value="20.00" class="radio addOn percentage" data-for="amount1" />Add Blue + 20%</div>
```

Your function adding must be called anytime you change anything, to allow you know what is changed, and set price to zero when changing the value (optional).

```
$('.amount').keydown(function () {
    $('.price label').text('0');
});

$('.amount').keyup(function () {
    changeAmount();
});

$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    changeAmount();
});
```

And last, depending on the class of checkbox clicked, different calculation:

```
function changeAmount() {
    var $amount = 0;

    $amount = parseFloat( $('.amount').val() ) * 20;
    if (isNaN($amount)) {
        $amount = 0;
    }

    var $add = 0;
    $('.add:checked').each(function () {
        $add += parseFloat( $(this).val() );
    });

    // Calculate percentage of the Base product
    if ( $('.percentage').is(":checked") ) {
        $amount = $amount * (1 + $('.percentage').val()/100 );
    }

    var $total = parseFloat( $amount + $add );

    $('.price label').text( $total.toFixed(0) )
}
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mGLfk/11/

Hope it likes you! XD

Comment: how do I changed from checkbox to radio? when i change the "checkbox" to "radio",  nothing happens. I changed jquery :checked to $radio:checked, but with no luck. Thanks

Comment: Where? I think you are confounding "radio" class with "radio" tag html. In jquery, you select elements with class with $('element.class') and specific subsets of HTML elements with pseudoselectors $('element:elementType'). $('input:checkbox') is for selecting checkboxs, $('.radio') will select ANY ELEMENT WITH CLASS RADIO

Comment: Right again! Man it's been a long day. It was the element type, changed $('input:checkbox') to $('.radio') and it worked. Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: I hate to ask this one, but is there a simple way to use (this) for the percentage other than repeating the code for percentage2,3, etc. for the buttons, i have lots to put in. see jquery on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EG9M4/

Comment: yes, but you're changing the case, XD. In the case above, you have a checkbox and you want to calculate only when is selected. Now, you have a radio button and you want calculate over the selected. In this case, you give the radio button the class percentage (to give any element with the class the behaviour) and select the percentage from the input radio button (see the change in line 32 of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EG9M4/1/). Look for "jQuery selectors" for more info, ;D

Comment: Last info, I learnt a huge amount of all I know about jQuery reading "jQuery: From Novice to Ninja", from Sitepoint, you should try to read it, it'll help you a lot with your development

Comment: thanks. this finishes me off with the questions. i am getting the book from Amazon. thanks again. your are, the master ninja!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it http://jsfiddle.net/mGLfk/10/
First, use keyup instead of keypress. I added two separate class for percent and sum.

```
function changeAmount($element) {
    var amount = 0;
    amount = parseFloat($element.val()) * 20;
    if (isNaN(amount)) {
        amount = 0;
    }
    var id = $element.attr('id');
    $('.sum.radio:checked[data-for="' + id + '"]').each(function () {
        amount += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    var percentage=100;
    $('.percent.radio:checked[data-for="' + id + '"]').each(function () {
        percentage += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    amount*=(percentage/100);
    $('label[for=' + id + ']').text(amount.toFixed(0))
}
```

Comment: yes, but the 1st checkbox does not work, If I have 2 checkboxes, #1 is 10% and #2 is 20%, if i click both, the total adds 30% to it. That is very close. I will work on it as well. Thanks